# Stranded writer has his leg hobbled by a woman

Tags: identify-this-movie

There was a movie about a man, a famous writer, who broke his leg in a snowstorm, and was given shelter in the "boondocks" by a woman. The storm lasted about a week, during which time the writer's leg healed, and he was ready to move on when the weather cleared.

But the woman, who had developed a "crush" on him, or at least his fame, didn't want to let him go, so she made plans to "hobble" him by re-breaking his leg. There was a fight, and he saved himself by crashing the (manual) typewriter on the woman's head, and escaping.

I saw this (American) movie while in Mexico in 1994. What movie was this?

Comment: Beware *not* to adapt the question to the answer. If you asked for a black and white movie, then you asked for a black and white movie. Only change it if you actually did *not remember* it to be black and white, *not* because the answer turned out not to be.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I saw it in "black and and white," but the answer noted, correctly, that I was  using a black and white Mexican TV, which sort of invalidates the point.

Comment: Still that was your question and you only changed it because the answer told you the movie is not in black and white. That is not how questions work here, not even those ID questions.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson What's the proper protocol? Ignore that he found the answer he was looking for and hope there's an actual black and white movie with the same premise?

Comment: The information that the poster saw it on TV could potentially be useful, but the fact that it was a black and white TV is surely irrelevant.  It seems to me the edit was wholly appropriate.

Comment: @Matthew Why? He can very well accept the answer if it's the correct one. Just adapating questions to answers is a bad thing, and has always been on SE. We don't tag it with the found movie once found either. Or add a [SOLVED] appendage to the title. A question is a question and an answer is an answer. It's not the system's fault that identification questions can result in such awkward situations.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson questions are *often* edited after the fact based on information that comes to light as part of an answer. Done right, it makes the question and answer both better, and as long as it does there's no sensible reason to avoid it. Everything here is editable for a reason.

Comment: I'd be amazed if entering a couple of keywords in Google wouldn't reveal "Misery" straight away. IMHO this question should have been closed due to ["lacking in research, i.e. being easily answered from an actor's name on IMDB or Wikipedia"](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @BCdotWEB: I did not know the name of either the actor or actress. In part, what you said about "stranded writer" is true, but only because it links to this post!

Comment: @TomAu The words ["writer snowstorm fan"](https://www.google.com/search?q=writer+snowstorm+fan) reveal "Misery" as the top result. ["movie writer fan typewriter"](https://www.google.com/search?q=movie+writer+fan+typewriter) also uncovers "Misery". Etc. The point is "lack of research", and a Google search should be the bare minimum.

Comment: @BCdotWEB: If I type these permutations without the word "fan," I get far fewer results. And even if it is "Top Ten" (say 7th or 8th), how would I know which one to choose. I can't do what you can.

Comment: @TomAu ["movie writer snowstorm typewriter"](https://www.google.com/search?q=movie%20writer%20snowstorm%20typewriter) gives "Misery" as the top result, and the novel as the second one. WRT "how would I know which one to choose": is it really too much effort to click a link and read a bit?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is definitely [Misery](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100157/combined) (1990) with James Caan and Kathy Bates (who won an Oscar for the role). Not sure why it was in B&W, maybe you saw it on a B&W TV?

> Best-selling novelist Paul Sheldon is on his way home from his Colorado hideaway after completing his latest book, when he crashes his car in a freak blizzard. Paul is critically injured, but is rescued by former nurse Annie Wilkes, Paul's "number one fan", who takes Paul back to her remote house in the mountains (without bothering to tell anybody). Unfortunately for Paul, Annie is also a headcase. When she discovers that Paul has killed off the heroine in her favorite novels, her reaction leaves Paul shattered (literally)...

It was based on a [Stephen King novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misery_%28novel%29) by the same name. Here's the trailer:

Comment: 1.5 minutes? Flagged for running a sock-puppet called *Tom Au*!

Comment: Yes, it was a black and white TV in Mexico, and I remember the woman's name being Annie.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Would've been even less if I saw it earlier... It's my favorite Stephen King book. :)

Comment: @Walt Well, congratulations then, with +4 after 5 minutes I can literally feel the "hotness" of this question. ;-)